# Gerar números aleatórios em um Array de 10 até 50

Tags: java, array, random, números-aleatórios, for

Como posso gerar um array de números aleatórios com um limite, devem ser números de 10 até 50.

Para gerar números aleatórios de 0 até 50 eu uso:

```
            Random random = new Random();
            int array[] = new int[5]; // 5 números serão gerados.

            for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
                 array[i] = random.nextInt(50); // Gera números aleatórios com limite 50.
                 System.out.println(array[i]); // Saída, são gerados 5 números.
            }
```

Gostaria de gerar números a partir de 10 até no máximo 50. ao invés de iniciar em 0.

Comment: Substitua `int i=0` por `int i=10`!

Comment: Isso não é possível, pois o "i" controla a posição do array e não os números gerados a partir do Random.

Comment: Verdade, viajei.. Da uma olhada [nessa resposta](http://stackoverflow.com/a/363692/4336024)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
 for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
             array[i] = 10 + random.nextInt(40); // Gera números aleatórios com limite 50 e minimo 10.
             System.out.println(array[i]); // Saída, são gerados 5 números.
        }
```

Comment: Obrigado, era isso mesmo que eu precisava.

Answer (score 3):

Um jeito bem simples é você fazer `random.nextint(40)` e sempre somar 10 ao resultado.

Assim se vier 0 somando 10 fica 10 (o minimo). e se vier 40 somando 10 fica 50 (o máximo).

Answer (score 1):

A "fórmula" é

`numRandomico = numMinimo + geraRandom(numMaximo-numMinimo)`